# compile xcode project file to send

Tags: xcode

As a freelancer for example you sometimes needs to take a project and make a file from it that can be run on any other device .

I know there is some way to create a file in Xcode, but i remember i have to set a provisional with the device id number of the relevant user .

Is there a way to create a file that EVERY one can run on their device to check it out, without register their device on apple portal ?

if yes- what are the steps? if not, what are the steps to the first way ?

Thanks .

Comment: you mean an `.ipa file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a file that EVERY one can run on their device to check it out, without register their device on apple portal ?

If you want to distribute applications to people without their UDID number, you have two options: the App Store (which is not suitable for beta testing) or by using an enterprise account (which does not let you distribute to people outside of your organisation).

> if yes- what are the steps? if not, what are the steps to the first way ?

There are step-by-step instructions on how to do this in Apple's developer portal.  Have you looked at this?  At what point do you get stuck?

Comment: `which does not let you distribute to people outside of your organisation` rly?

Comment: Yes.  Check your contract.

Comment: with Testflight i need the udid ?

Comment: Testflight is only a method for distributing the IPAs.  It doesn't change how they must be signed.  Testflight can't bypass Apple's requirements.  If you need the UDID without Testflight, then you need the UDID with Testflight.